# How to write code to automatically resize table in ssrs reporting services before printing

Tags: reporting-services

I have a bunch of reports that are all tables in reporting services that I need to format for printing. Most print fine, but some have rows that take up more room than there is on the page and it cuts them off for printing. Is it possible to write a program in the custom code box to check if the rows are longer than the page and if they are resize it. How can I do this, what references do I use?

Comment: please provide one screen shot to understand your query more better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resize tables for printing - just ensure your page, report ans margin sizes all match the size of paper you are printing to - A4?